# Groupby, means and std

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to python ... thank you in advance!

I need to group, calculate in a column the mean for each nutrient and the corresponding std. 
As so:
cod | Nmean | Nstd | etc...for each nutrient

I managed to group and calculate the mean. But I need another column, for example, next to N%, with it's std ... and so on...

```
report = my_data.groupby(["cod"], as_index = False)[['N%', 'P%','K%', 'Ca%', 'Mg%', 'S%',
                                                'Fe mg/kg', 'Mn mg/kg', 'Zn mg/kg', 'Cu mg/kg', 
                                                'B mg/kg', 'Na mg/kg']].mean()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a `dict` comprehension with each of the column as key and `['mean', 'std']` as value first -

```
groups_agg = { i:['mean', 'std'] for i in ['N%', 'P%','K%', 'Ca%', 'Mg%', 'S%', 'Fe mg/kg', 'Mn mg/kg', 'Zn mg/kg', 'Cu mg/kg', 'B mg/kg', 'Na mg/kg'] }
```

It will look like this -

```
{'B mg/kg': ['mean', 'std'],
 'Ca%': ['mean', 'std'],
 'Cu mg/kg': ['mean', 'std'],
 'Fe mg/kg': ['mean', 'std'],
 'K%': ['mean', 'std'],
 'Mg%': ['mean', 'std'],
 'Mn mg/kg': ['mean', 'std'],
 'N%': ['mean', 'std'],
 'Na mg/kg': ['mean', 'std'],
 'P%': ['mean', 'std'],
 'S%': ['mean', 'std'],
 'Zn mg/kg': ['mean', 'std']}
```

Then pass on the object to [`pd.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

```
my_data.groupby(["cod"], as_index = False).agg(groups_agg)
```

Comment: Worked very good. Is there any simple way to add a " ± " next to the std ?

Comment: I don't think so :(. But that can be achieved easily by having another column - `my_data2['Mean_STD'] = my_data2['mean'] + (2*my_data2['std'])`. The negative can have another column